# Get likes from post instagram python

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

I want to scrape data from instagram post. I can get photo links, likes count and comments count, but I can’t get usernames of people who liked posts and comments from people. I use pyInstaParser. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Looking for this too!!

Comment: Seems a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916810/how-to-web-scrape-users-who-liked-an-instagram-picture

Answer (score 0):

I made this awhile back but this should work for what you're trying to do (uses https proxies to prevent Instagram limiting requests)

```
import requests, sys, time
from random import choice
if len(sys.argv) < 2:sys.exit(f"Usage: {sys.argv[0]} <Post Link> <Proxy List>")


Comments = 0
ProxList = []
Prox = open(sys.argv[2], "r")readlines()
for line in ReadProx:
    ProxList.append(line.strip('\n'))

while True:
    try:
        g = requests.get(sys.argv[1], proxies={'https://': 'https://'+choice(ProxList)})
        print(g.json())
        time.sleep(5)
        if len(g.json()['data']['shortcode_media']['edge_liked_by']['count']) > Comments:
            print(f"[+] Like | {g.json()['data']['shortcode_media']['edge_liked_by']['edges'][int(Comments)]['node']['username']}")
            if len(g.json()['data']['shortcode_media']['edge_liked_by']['count']) == Comments - 1:
                pass
            else:
                Comments += 1
        time.sleep(1.5)     
    except KeyboardInterrupt: sys.exit("Done")
    except Exception as e: print(e)
```