# How to web scrape users who liked an instagram picture?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, instagram

How would I go about gathering this kind of data from Instagram for a web scraping project, I tried myself to get it using beautifulsoup and requests true parsing the whole page:
but it doesn't work

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
usrs=[]
soup=BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/Bziq7f2C-jM/").content,'html.parser')
elem1=soup.find_all('div',class_="EtaWk")
#elem1 contains all the usernames within it 
if elem1:
    elem2=elem1.find('ul',class_="XQXOT")
    if elem2:
        xelems=elem2.findAll('ul',class_="Mr508")
        for i in range(len(xelems)):
            lis=xelems[i].find('a',class_="FPmhX notranslate TlrDj",title=True)
            usrs.append(a["title"])
```

Comment: Could you expand on *"doesn't work"*? Most of Instagram will be rendered with JavaScript, I doubt there's much *content* in what you're requesting and `FPmhX notranslate TlrDj` doesn't seem likely to be stable. You should do this via the API.

Comment: how can I do this with the IG api ,is it possible

Comment: Head to https://www.instagram.com/developer/ and find out

Comment: looks like I need a website in order to get an api

Comment: is there another way to do that

Comment: preferably include the code you posted as picture as actual code by editing and updating your question. (From Review).

Comment: now it is please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not a requirement for you to use Beautifulsoup and parse the HTML response yourself, there is [Instaloader](https://instaloader.github.io/), a Python library that allows to access Instagram very easily. After doing `pip install instaloader` to install it, you can do

```
import instaloader
L = instaloader.Instaloader()
Post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(L.context, 'Bziq7f2C-jM')
```

Then, `Post.get_likes()` returns an Iterator over the Profiles that have liked the Post, so to print all the usernames, you can do

```
for like in Post.get_likes():
    print(like.username)
```

Besides being an easy solution, Instaloader has also the advantage that it handles rate limiting automatically, and that it supports handling login and accessing posts of private profiles.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help